# Why the return type valuated as (boolean | function)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

In the next example, I want to explain the type of `toggle` function from `useDialog` hook.

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [isOpen, toggle] = useDialog(false);

  return (
    <>
      {isOpen ? `open` : `close`}
      <br />
      <button onClick={toggle}>Toggle</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

When typing the property:

```
const useDialog = (initial: boolean) => {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(initial);
  const toggle = () => setOpen(p => !p);

  // toggle typed as boolean | (() => void)
  return [isOpen, toggle];
};
```

`toggle` function evaluated as `boolean | (() => void)`.

While typing the function results `() => void`:

```
type Hook = (initialState: boolean) => [boolean, () => void];

// Works fine
const useDialog: Hook = initialState => {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(initialState);
  const toggle = () => setOpen(p => !p);

  // toggle typed as (() => void)
  return [isOpen, toggle];
};
```

What is the explanation for it?

[image: Edit toggle type]

Comment: It's a [bug in typeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32465)

Comment: It is not. This is intended behavior, and is why `as const` exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array is first and foremost, a list.

```
const arr = [1, "a", true]; // arr is typed (number | string | boolean)[]
```

This is intentional. It is the primary use-case of an array.

React hooks popularized the use of arrays as tuples (this pattern existed before them but suddenly it's hyped), and TypeScript does support this usecase:

```
const arr = [1, "a", true] as const; // arr is typed readonly [1, "a", true]
```

In your example, if you were to `return [isOpen, toggle] as const;` you would be able to destructure it on the other side without annotating any types.

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABCAzgUwMpwLZqgCxjAHMAKADwC5EAjOOAGzQEMwBKRAbwChE-EICFFEQBPRAF5EpDhIB8XRAF9uvfgCc8IdUgDa5ADRiAuomYoBQqAG5uK7oLDDEu4cyhoj6KBiju0plKomDh4hCSkUOogaGy23G4e1ogA9Cm09EysCXi+-slp0rIKAG5wMAAm3EA)

Answer (score 0):

In this case:

```
const useDialog = (initial: boolean) => {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(initial);
  const toggle = () => setOpen(p => !p);

  // toggle typed as boolean | (() => void)
  return [isOpen, toggle];
};
```

The type of `toggle` is `() => void`, but the return type of the `useDialog` hook itself would be `(boolean | (() => void))` because you return an array which values are indeed `boolean` or `() => void` functions, and so if you use this hook in a component, the compiler would only know that the return value is an array, and each item is either a `boolean` OR a `() => void` function.

For the second case you type the return value of the hook explicitly, so the compiler will now that you are return an array which values are exactly one `boolean` then exactly one `() => void` function, and in that order.

Comment: I wonder why it's `boolean` OR `function`, as it returns a sorted array where you already know that the types are `[boolean,function]`